# Jhipster/ SpringBoot- Loading property file dynamically

Tags: java, spring, jhipster, resourcebundle

I have a jhipster/ SpringBoot web-application. On UI I need to show a drop down whoes values are coming from a .properties file.

This property file can be edited while the application is running and changes should be reflected on UI without a server restart.

I have tried using commons.config FileChangedReloadingStrategy and normal loading of property file as stream but nothing worked.
I have also tried ResourceBundleMessageSource with setCacheSeconds(1) but still it is not showing the latest changes.

Please note that .propeties file is inside the java/main/resources folder as it is a Maven project.

I don't want to put it outside WAR and then adding that path in the classpath.

What will be the best way to achive this?